# http.Client POST read response before sending body

Tags: go

Is there a way to do a `client.Do("POST", "example.com", body)` and read the response headers before the entire response body has been received/closed? This would be similar to how JavaScript XHR requests emit an event that the headers have been received and you can read them before the rest of the request arrives.

What I'm trying to accomplish is making a sort of "smart client" that uses information in the headers from my server to determine what to upload in the request body. So I need to start the request, read the response headers, then start writing to the request body. Because of the nature of my system, I can't split it across separate requests. I believe it's possible at the protocol level, but I'm not sure if go's http libraries support it.

Comment: While this would be in theory possible at the protocol level it would conflict with the response follows request paradigm of HTTP. It might also lead to problems with proxies, especially if these want to analyze the content first before forwarding (i.e. secure gateways). The proper scheme would be instead to have a "preflight" request to find out what the server expects and then a new request which then provides what the server expects.

Comment: I agree multiple requests would be more idiomatic of HTTP. However, that's very undesirable with what I'm trying to do. Can proxies still cause issues if I'm using HTTPS all the way from the client to my server?

Comment: Proxies might do SSL interception - which is common in companies but also often done with desktop antivirus. In this case it does not really matter if HTTP or HTTPS is used since the analysis is done in both cases. In short: better use HTTP(S) as intended and don't try to invent some shortcut which works in your current environment and use case but might cause unexpected problems later in different cases.

Comment: That makes sense. It really seems orthogonal to the problem I'm trying to solve though. Why would a proxy be more likely to intercept my header if it's sent in the original request vs a preflight request?

Comment: A proxy is more likely to expect common semantics of HTTP, i.e. send a full request and get a full response instead of getting only the request header, then the response header etc. Apart from that: the standard has a feature where the server first sends a provisional response header and then the real header+body. The client must announce support for this though and a proxy might filter this support if he cannot deal with it. See [100 Continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/100) for more.

Comment: The server shouldn't be *sending* a response until you finish sending the body. There's nothing you can do client-side to start reading that which has not yet been sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http client Do function doesn't block until whole response body is returned. if you don't want to read full response, why not just use res.Body.Close() after you have examined headers?. i think it should work if you want roughly same behavior. According to Doc.

> The response body is streamed on demand as the Body field is read. If the network 
>   connection fails or the server terminates the response, Body.Read calls return an error.

Although DefaultTransport of default http.Client which is http.Transport doesn't give you guarantee that it won't read any byte before you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You can fulfill your requirements by sending an `OPTIONS` request to the url before sending actual request and read the response header.

The response header will contain all the necessary headers to perform the preferred request.

```golang
req, _ := http.NewRequest("OPTIONS", "example.com", nil)

resp, _ := client.Do(req)
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, sending multiple requests isn't an option for my system.